# Query model based on value inside one of its columns

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model called staff. One of the staff columns is called locations which holds the id's of all the locations this staff is available at. I want to create a query that uses a Location ID to get all staff active at that location. How can I do that using the ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I have understood your question correctly and your locations column contains CSV data, then you need to use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) -

```
Staff.findAll({
    where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('FIND_IN_SET', locationId, sequelize.col('locations')), {[Op.gt]: 0})
})
```

A better option would be to normalize your data as this query is non-SARGable.

Comment: This worked. Well, partially since I had to remove the greater than operator at the end

Answer (score 0):

In Sequelize, you can perform a query to filter staff based on their locations using the include and where options in your query.

```php
const staff = await Staff.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Location,
      as: 'locations',
      where: { id: locationId },
      through: { attributes: [] }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: Will this work if the models are not linked?

Answer (score 0):

const findStaff = await StaffModel.findAll({
where: {
locationId: "your locationId"
}
})

Comment: This won't work as the column for locations holds multiple location ID's